# Custom markers - Google App maker

Tags: google-app-maker

I am trying to display a custom marker on the map in App maker but unfortunately, I am unable to do so,

previously I was able to achieve this simply by

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

position:{lat:, lng:},
map:map,
icon: url

});
```

please assist

Comment: it is normal your `lat` and `lng` are empty ?

Comment: I purposely left them out.

Comment: on the [API page of google Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/custom-markers) they say you need to use a `new google.maps.LatLng(42, 666)` for the position maybe that'l change something ?

Comment: I have an html widget on the page and I am calling it like this 
var div = app.pages.GmapCanvase.descendants.MapDiv.getElement();
and importing it to google maps like this
       ` map = new google.maps.Map(div, {
          zoom: 16,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91722, 151.23064),
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });
`

but it is not working.

Comment: It says Cannot read property 'Map' of undefined from map = new google.maps.Map()

Answer (score 1):

If you use a Google Map widget, you can set those properties like so:

```
var map = app.pages.GmapCanvase.descendants.MapDiv;
map.mapType = 'roadmap';
map.zoom = 16;
map.latitude = -33.91722;
map.longitude = 151.23064;
var marker = map.getAddressMarkerJs();
marker.setIcon(url);
```